# OpenLayers add white background to image/png geoserver layer

Tags: geoserver, wms, openlayers, image, transparency-opacity

i created a new wms layer in openlayers. i get the layer from geoserver as  image/png and transparent=true.

openlayers rotate the raster 30 deg (due to its coordinates - it's fine!) but add white background. the white background start to disappear when zooming in.

how i prevent openlayers from adding white background to raster after rotate? (openlayers setteing? geoserver settings?)

Comment: Are you sure that "OL" is responsible?, or could be Geoserver?

Comment: It can be also geoserver. I dont know why ol show the image with white background